# EXCEL won't link to Internet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, url

I have downloaded data from a website that contains links to other website.  When I click on any of the URLs in EXCEL I get the message :
"This operartion has been canceled due to restriction in effect on this computer. Please contact your systems adminstrator."

The issus is that this is my personal computer so I should be the system admin.

Comment: Because you posted this, I searched the web since I have a similar problem in upgrading a program. It appears that it is malware causing the problem. See http://www.rarst.net/software/operation-has-been-cancelled/

Answer (score 0):

Better you reset your Browser settings

> Goto Tools > Internet Options > Advanced tab > Reset From the Reset
>   Internet Explorer Settings window, select the Delete personal settings
>   check box, and then click Reset

After resetting, select a [default program](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310049#LetMeFixItMyselfAlways) from Internet options > Internet programs > Set your default program

There is a [Microsoft fix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310049) for doing this 
.